# Use Azure Storage Emulator for Dapr Local Development

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-storage-emulator, dapr

For local development / debugging we setup our Dapr Components to run with docker-compose.
One of the components uses an [Azure Event Hub Input Binding](https://docs.dapr.io/reference/components-reference/supported-bindings/eventhubs/).
To keep the event streams separat per developer we created dedicated Consumer Groups and dedicated Storage Containers to store the Checkpoints.

I would like to use the Azure Storage Emulator for the local development scenario to simplify the development setup. However the Storage Container [Configuration](https://docs.dapr.io/reference/components-reference/supported-bindings/eventhubs/#spec-metadata-fields) only allows to configure storageAccountName, storageAccountKey and storageContainerName.

Is there any chance to configure the Dapr Event Hub Binding to use Azure Storage Emulator instead of cloud hosted storage accounts ?

Comment: Have you tried to use [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite) as side-car and route blob clients traffic to azurite?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Martin! I haven't tried it but i'm not sure how it can help when i can't configure the full hostname of the blob account. If i understand it correctly, Azurite would provide kind or a storage account as docker container which would have a Hostname within the docker network. But i'm not free to configure this hostname as i can only provide the storage account name which then gets extended to a something like https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that this request has already been raised in 2020 but it's not possible at the moment.

https://github.com/dapr/components-contrib/issues/279